# Mute the soundmanager plugin sounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, soundmanager2

I used soundmanager to playing sounds on my website. I have this code:

```
soundManager.setup({
    debugMode: false,
    url: 'http://www.newdayatwork.com/wp-content/themes/roots/static/swf/',
});

soundManager.onready(function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id:'soundLaag1',
        url: 'http://www.newdayatwork.com/wp-content/themes/roots/static/wav/laag1.wav'
    });
    soundManager.createSound({
        id:'soundLaag2',
        url: 'http://www.newdayatwork.com/wp-content/themes/roots/static/wav/laag2.wav'
});

$(document).on('click', '.nav-main li', function(e) {
    var item = $(this).attr('class');

    switch (item) {
        case 'menu-imagine active':
        case 'menu-visie active':
            soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
            break;

        case 'menu-workspace active':
        case 'menu-werkplek active':
            soundManager.play('soundLaag2');
            break;

        default:
            soundManager.play('soundMidden1');
            break;
    }
});

$('.menu-sound').click(function() {
     soundManager.mute();
});
```

When you click on a navigation item. Than you have a sound playing. But now the problem. I have a button on my website. You can mute the sounds on the website. But this is not working. When i click on the menu-sound button. I doing this: soundManager.mute();

But than is only the sound off on that page. When you click on that button. But when you click them. Should the sound on the entire website out.

How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-geluid, .menu-sound').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('body').removeClass('mute');
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('mute');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
```